# How to not return a value when using prisma findFirst() where the value is undefined

Tags: node.js, prisma, express-session

I'm working at the new database because it's convenient to use in my opinion, but when the user is logged out, `req.session.userId` will be undefined. So when I'm use `findFirst()` function with `{ where : req.session.userId }`. If the `req.session.userId` is undefined. The `findFirst()` is still return the first record the the table.
How do I fix that `findFirst()` must not return the value when `req.session.userId` is undefined.

It's kind of equivalent to the MySQL Query Command.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = req.session.userId;
```

My Prisma query code.

```
app.use(async (req,res, next)=>{
  let user

  user = await database.user.findFirst({where:{
    id: req.session.userId
  }})

  req.user = user
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always choose not to call DB in that case:

```
app.use(async (req,res, next)=>{
  let user

  user = req.session.userId && await database.user.findFirst({where:{
    id: req.session.userId
  }})

  req.user = user
  next()
})
```

Only if userId is not undefined you will call your database. And in case it is undefined, your response will have `user: undefined`, unless you want to send some other response in this case, but the your initial value setting of user should be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(async (req,res, next)=>{
const  user = await database.user.findFirst({where:{{
   OR : [
     {
   id: req.session.userId
 },
{
   id: 'undefined'
 }
   ]
}})

 req.user = user
 next()
})
```